# google.load call back in coffeescript class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to include google charts from here[enter link description here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) using the [google loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) as explained in the snippet. My problem is that when I call the `new google.visualization.DataTable` the visualization is not yet loaded and the javascript fails.

If I then try the same command in the JS console, the call is successful.

I believe in this case I should be using a callback to know when the library is successfully loaded.

I'm trying to configure it but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class @Charts
  constructor: ->
    @log = new Logger "Charts"
    @ready = false
    google.load 'visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': @pageLoaded}
    @log.debug "google load called"    

  pageLoaded: ->
    @log.debug "google library loaded"
    @ready = true

  waitReady: ->
    setTimeout(@log.debug("wait"), 2000) while not @ready

  drawactionStatuses: (data) ->
    @waitReady()
    @log.debug "drawing donut"

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
    data.addColumn "string", "Status"
    data.addColumn "number", "Number of actions"
    data.addRows data

    # Set chart options
    options =
      title: "action statuses"
      width: 400
      height: 300


    # Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("action_statuses"))
    chart.draw data, options
```

The logs on the console are:

```
Charts : INFO : logging ready
Charts : DEBUG : google load called
Charts : DEBUG : drawing donut
```

Also the `waitReady` function doesn't seem to work

Comment: _"My problem is that when I call the `new google.visualization.DataTable` the visualization is not yet loaded and the javascript fails."_ I don't know "google visualization" but AFAICS from your code, the library is loaded in the constructor. And the table created in a method. So it _should_ have been loaded before you use it. Do you have some means to log is the load was successful?

Answer (score 1):

> I should be using a callback to know when the library is successfully loaded

As I said in a comment, I don't know the [Google Loader Library](https://developers.google.com/loader/#GoogleLoad) -- so take this as hypothetical until someone confirm or infirm it, but...

Though, you have to remember your callback is a *function*. So it will be invoked by the library without being bound there to any object. So, you have to somehow bound your callback to `this` yourself. In CoffeeScript the *fat arrow* `=>` exists for that exact purpose. You could use it either when defining your callback *or* when passing it:

**When passing the callback**

```
google.load 'visualization', '1.0', 
            { 'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': => @pageLoaded() }
#                                                   ^^            ^^


  pageLoaded: ->
    @log.debug "google library loaded"
    @ready = true
```

---

**When defining the callback**

Alternatively, you might use the *fat arrow* to bound `pageLoaded` on its definition site:

```
google.load 'visualization', '1.0', 
            { 'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': @pageLoaded }

  pageLoaded: =>
  #           ^
    @log.debug "google library loaded"
    @ready = true
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, though my waitReady doesn't delay the execution, I think I'm using the wrong approach here. any clues?

Comment: Thank you, in the end with the callback stuff and with waiting for the page to be loaded it was too complicate, I just placed the initializer as a static call in the headers, so my coffeescript/jquery implicitily waits for it to be load when I do `$ -> ...` thanks